# Dynamically adding elements to array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array with a dynamic number of elements (it's a list of words generated by users).

I would like to be able to divide the array elements by 3 at anytime:

My thoughts were to count the elements in the array (using `count($myArray)`) and if the modulus != 0 I would recursively add elements until it does.

Here is my code:

```
function adjustArray($myArray, $lineLimit = 3){
    $count = count($myArray);

    if ($count % $lineLimit != 0):
        $myArray[] = '';
        adjustArray($myArray, $lineLimit);

    else:
        return $myArray; //problem when returning is conditional (return won't work - returns NULL
    endif;

}
```

How can I fix this code, or better yet, how can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: "how can I do this more efficiently" --- it's not suitable for the broken code. How can you write more efficiently a broken code? Put your cat on the keyboard - it will generate some for you.

Comment: Anyway, your explanation isn't clear enough

Comment: what i meant was how can i get the results i want using a more efficient method :) obviously not with the current code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion here. Simply add the number of elements needed in order to make the length a multiple of 3:

```
function adjustArray($myArray, $lineLimit = 3){
    $count = count($myArray);

    if ($count % $lineLimit != 0){
        for($i = 0; $i < $lineLimit - $count % $lineLimit; $i++)
            $myArray[] = "";
    }   

    return $myArray;
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://codepad.org/6viL1peq

Alternatively, you could use:

```
$myArray = array_merge($myArray, array_fill(0, $lineLimit - $count % $lineLimit, ""));
```

instead of a loop, to make it even faster.

A demonstration of this approach can be found [here](http://ideone.com/777qyc).

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a while loop so you don't have the overhead of making function calls.

```
while(count($myArray) % $lineLimit !=0){
  $myArray[] = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response! Asad bead you to it (so i marked his as correct)